# explain and show example why we use $CONDITIONS in sqoop

Tags: sqoop

sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/retail_db --username root --password cloudera --query 'select * from table name where $CONDITIONS'

Comment: Please write your question clearly with proper examples and code. Please don't write questions in a rush for people to help you in the right direction :)  See this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import the results of a query in parallel, then each map task will need to execute a copy of the query, with results partitioned by bounding conditions inferred by Sqoop. Your query must include the token $CONDITIONS which each Sqoop process will replace with a unique condition expression. You must also select a splitting column with --split-by.

```
$ sqoop import \
--query 'SELECT a.*, b.* FROM a JOIN b on (a.id == b.id) WHERE $CONDITIONS' \
--split-by a.id 
--target-dir /user/foo/joinresults
```